# Dynamics CRM 2011 - View not displaying related information

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to create a view that will display data from an order. There is a one to many relationship from the order to the payments for an order. The payments will display on the order form. The problem I'm having is that the information from the payment does not display when you run the query. Here is the XML from the view.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    -<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
    -<entity name="salesorder"><attribute name="name"/>
         <attribute name="customerid"/>
         <attribute name="totalamount"/>
         <attribute name="salesorderid"/>
         <order descending="false" attribute="name"/>
    -<filter type="and"><condition attribute="totalamountlessfreight" value="0"
           operator="gt"/>
         <condition attribute="ree_orderdate" operator="this-month"/>
     </filter>
    -<link-entity name="ree_salesorderpayment" alias="a_eaddfe488ba0e2118a9d78e3b508542d" link-         type="outer" visible="false" to="ree_payment" from="ree_salesorderpaymentid">
         <attribute name="ree_paymentdate"/>
         <attribute name="ree_paymentamount"/>
     </link-entity> 
     </entity></fetch>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Did you create this XML? One cool new thing is the Advanced Find you can download the FecthXml. And in Advanced Find you can change the filters and see where your query is failing.

EDIT: In Advanced find you can set all query you want, make filters (just add columns and apply the operators AND and OR) and you can make joins when you want filter a related entity. After that you can download the FetchXML, so we have sure that FetchXML is well formatted. If don't get any records the problem is in your data and not in FetchXML, so i advised you remove the filters to know where are the problems.

I don't know which login you are but if you aren't using an administrator it's possible you catch something about security permissions.

You can try change the entities, make the query to ree_salesorderpayment entity and after make a join with salesorder.

Comment: I downloaded the XML. I'll check out the filters. Thanks

Comment: I don't see a Filter anywhere on the Advanced Find window. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: The filter appear when you add a column to filter. Take a look in this [article](http://blog.xrm.com/index.php/2011/11/lets-crm-online-2011-advanced-find-part-1/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the point is. Your just talking about creating the query. I've done that and it doesn't work. That is how I got the XML listed above.

Comment: Is there a way to import the FetchXML after you change it? Thanks

Comment: No, the only option supported is you apply in a report. Another option UNSUPPORTED is you edit the solution file (when you export), in this files you have a xml node called savedquerys, you can change the FetchXML associated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Stunnware Tools](http://www.stunnware.com/products/tools4/download.htm) app is old but still good for FetchXML.  One thing I've noticed before ref strange behaviour with queries is that if there are currency fields behaving oddly, then adding the transactioncurrencyid field to the columns can help.